# Javafx 2D maze standard solution not working

Tags: java, algorithm, javafx, maze

I have looked at a lot of threads and found what I thought was a solution to a standard Java maze my solveMaze method is:

```
    if (done(r, c)) {// if within Goal stop and return this maze
        return this;
    } else if (r > 1 && getCell(r - 1, c) == ' ') {
        setCell(r - 1, c, '*');
        return solveMaze(r - 1, c);
    } else if (r < maxRow - 1 && getCell(r + 1, c) == ' ') {
        setCell(r + 1, c, '*');
        return solveMaze(r + 1, c);
    } else if (c < maxCol - 1 && getCell(r, c + 1) == ' ') {
        setCell(r, c + 1, '*');
        return solveMaze(r, c + 1);

    } else if (c > 1 && getCell(r, c - 1) == ' ') {
        setCell(r, c - 1, '*');
        return solveMaze(r, c - 1);
    } else {
        return null;// solveMaze(r, c);
    }
```

but it doesn't go to goal instead it ends half way through
[end result of maze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF7Fw.png)

I am guessing this is because the method has to return something and I return null at the end, but I have also tried to make this a void method and it does the same thing.  I have tried to get rid of the r and c restraints and then I get array out of bounds exceptions.

I just dont see why the code doesn't work when it is essentially the standard code.

Here it is as a void:

```
    if (done(r, c)) {// if within Goal stop and return this maze
        return ;
    } else if (r > 1 && getCell(r - 1, c) == ' ') {
        setCell(r - 1, c, '*');
         solveMaze(r - 1, c);
    } else if (r < maxRow - 1 && getCell(r + 1, c) == ' ') {
        setCell(r + 1, c, '*');
         solveMaze(r + 1, c);
    } else if (c < maxCol - 1 && getCell(r, c + 1) == ' ') {
        setCell(r, c + 1, '*');
         solveMaze(r, c + 1);

    } else if (c > 1 && getCell(r, c - 1) == ' ') {
        setCell(r, c - 1, '*');
         solveMaze(r, c - 1);
    }
```

I have also tried do the not equal to since walls are designated as - and | I had

```
    if (done(r, c)) {// if within Goal stop and return this maze
        return this;
    } else if (r > 1 && getCell(r - 1, c) != '|' && getCell(r - 1, c) != '*' && getCell(r, c + 1) != '+'
            && getCell(r, c + 1) != 'S') {
        System.out.println(getCell(r - 1, c) + "r " + r + " c " + c);
        setCell(r - 1, c, '*');
        return solveMaze(r - 1, c);
    } else if (r < maxRow - 1 && getCell(r + 1, c) != '|' && getCell(r + 1, c) != '*' && getCell(r, c + 1) != '+'
            && getCell(r, c + 1) != 'S') {
        System.out.println(getCell(r + 1, c) + "r " + r + " c " + c);
        setCell(r + 1, c, '*');
        return solveMaze(r + 1, c);
    } else if (c < maxCol - 1 && getCell(r, c + 1) != '-' && getCell(r, c + 1) != '*' && getCell(r, c + 1) != '+'
            && getCell(r, c + 1) != 'S') {
        System.out.println(getCell(r, c + 1) + "r " + r + " c " + c);
        setCell(r, c + 1, '*');
        return solveMaze(r, c + 1);

    } else if (c > 1 && getCell(r, c - 1) != '-' && getCell(r, c - 1) != '*' && getCell(r, c + 1) != '+'
            && getCell(r, c + 1) != 'S') {
        System.out.println(getCell(r, c - 1) + "r " + r + " c " + c);
        setCell(r, c - 1, '*');
        return solveMaze(r, c - 1);
    } else {
        System.out.println(getCell(r, c) + "r " + r + " c " + c);
        return null;// solveMaze(r, c);
    }
}
```

So any ideas what I should try next?
Thanks

Comment: I think your solver ran out of valid squares so it just ended. You should look into backtracking to get to all the possible locations

Comment: Any path finding algorithm would do the trick. If you want to do backtracking though, you need to learn how it actually works. In this case it's easy to see why your algorithm doesn't work. In every call of the `solveMaze` method only considers a single possibility let alone undo any changes in case the goal is not found on a certain branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have solves the maze with a particular priority, which is U, D, R, L, but does not backtrack to find all solutions.

Given the map, and your priorities, from the start your code went R first (it could not go Up or Down), then Up at the first opportunity until it hit walls, and then stopped (when there were no valid movements anymore).

You need to remove the `else if` structure, which does not permit backtracking.  During backtracking, clear the position (it was marked as a `*`, it needs to restore back to an empty space).

The following should work, but is not tested (you may need a static boolean `solved` variable, which allows all recursion to return immediately: `if (solved) return;`.

```
if (solved)
    return;
if (done(r, c)) {// if within Goal stop and return this maze
    solved=true;
    return ;
} 
if (r > 1 && getCell(r - 1, c) == ' ') {  // Try up first
    setCell(r - 1, c, '*');
    solveMaze(r - 1, c);
    setCell(r - 1, c, ' ');  // Restore the cell back to open and keep trying
} 
if (r < maxRow - 1 && getCell(r + 1, c) == ' ') {  // Down
    setCell(r + 1, c, '*');
    solveMaze(r + 1, c);
    setCell(r + 1, c, ' ');  // Restore the cell back to open and keep trying
} 
if (c < maxCol - 1 && getCell(r, c + 1) == ' ') {  // Right
    setCell(r, c + 1, '*');
    solveMaze(r, c + 1);
    setCell(r, c + 1, ' ');
} 
if (c > 1 && getCell(r, c - 1) == ' ') {  // Left
    setCell(r, c - 1, '*');
     solveMaze(r, c - 1);
    setCell(r, c - 1, ' ');
}
```

Comment: That worked great!  everything I had was an else if but making it and if makes total sense Here is the tested and working code if anyone else needs it int he future, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (solved)
        return null;
    if (done(r, c)) {// if within Goal stop and return this maze
        solved = true;
        return null;
    }
    if (r > 1 && getCell(r - 1, c) == ' ') {// Up goes first
        setCell(r - 1, c, '*');
        solveMaze(r - 1, c);
        if (solved)
            return null;
        setCell(r - 1, c, ' ');
    }
    if (r < maxRow - 1 && getCell(r + 1, c) == ' ') {// Down
        setCell(r + 1, c, '*');
        solveMaze(r + 1, c);
        if (solved)
            return null;
        setCell(r + 1, c, ' ');
    }
    if (c < maxCol - 1 && getCell(r, c + 1) == ' ') {// Right
        setCell(r, c + 1, '*');
        solveMaze(r, c + 1);
        if (solved)
            return null;
        setCell(r, c + 1, ' ');
    }
    if (c > 1 && getCell(r, c - 1) == ' ') { // Left
        setCell(r, c - 1, '*');
        solveMaze(r, c - 1);
        if (solved)
            return null;
        setCell(r, c - 1, ' ');
    }

    return null;
```